# Use x11 with a windows client and a linux server

Tags: ssh, rhel, x11, windows

I've been trying to use X11 with my local server for quite a while, but i'm unable to with the built in windows ssh client. Does someone has a way to fix it ? I've tried a lot of tutorials to fix it like, using xhost or but i always get a `unable to open display` whatever i try to open.

`X11Forwarding yes` is of course set on my server.

Tell me if you need anything to help me as i don't really know what to send.
My display variable is set to `127.0.0.1:0` on my windows and i have the -Y flag on.

Comment: the windows SSH client is not an X server. So, are you maybe missing an X server?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem, I thought the build-in ssh server of windows had a xserver included. Thank you

Comment: that's not an ssh server, that's an ssh client! But yeah, SSH and X are simply separate things :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows is lacking a X Server, It was what i was missing. Thanks @marcus-müller for the answer.

Comment: While you can integrate an X server with the native MS-Windows openssh client or putty, its a bit of a pain - you might want to try mobaxterm for a simple solution.